# How to measure which spark gap is firing, in a type of Tesla coil, using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, tesla-coil

Firstly, I am teaching myself electronics and do not know all the lingo at this point in time.

With that said, I have conceptualized a fun(?) project in the back of my mind which consists of multiple spark gaps (inspired by Tesla coils.)

What I want to do is measure which spark gap fires (A, B or C) and then record the data using an Arduino.

Building the circuit is pretty trivial, recording it without damaging anything is a bit out of my pay grade at this stage in my "career."

The circuit will look like something like this where the sensor would be the "secondary" coil in a typical Tesla coil arrangement (although I do not need the super high voltage.)

[image: Sparky!]

How would I use the sensor (or secondary coil) to tell the Arduino, that spark gap A,B or C has just fired?

Comment: High voltage and Arduino don't go together in the same sentence well. How about using a fast photo-sensor with a tube or light-guide to keep a distance and keep out stray light?

Comment: Thats a good idea.

Comment: A piece of plastic fiber optic strand would be more than good enough. You can get this at craft stores. Or re-purpose some TOSLink cables.